# How to listen an onclick event for <a> element built using AngularJS through Browser Console

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have an HTML page. The entire document is built using AngularJS.

HTML document and  element

```
<html ng-app="appName">
...
<a translate="" href="/tst" class="link ng-scope">Test</a>
..
</html>
```

I want to listen for the onClick event that occurs when a user clicks on the  element in console. How would i do that. What should be the scope? and how i can attach onclick event for this  element like "addEventListener" in plain JS.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "in console"

Comment: the one which we can see when we enable debugger opiton or if we use FireBug addon

Comment: What exactly you want to do on click of the element. If you all need to is listen to event, and dont need angular related thingies, then you can use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener

Comment: So why not use jquery $ or simple javascript ?

Comment: @originof, yes i can use jQuery or JavaScript. But, I want to know how it is done using Angular. By using $scope,$watch or $broadcast?

Comment: You can't without adding ng-click directive, so, the question is, how you can add ng-click dinamically ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use ng-click in the element like :

```
<a translate="" href="/tst" ng-click="handleClick()" class="link ng-scope">Test</a>
```

And can use the function in your controller like :

```
$scope.handleClick = function()
{
   console.log("Element clicked");
}
```

In this case scope should be current view controller scope
Thanks

Comment: I am not going to make any change to the page itself. I am just trying to add the listener in debugger console for the element

Comment: You could select this anchor in JQuery and subscribe for click event

Comment: For that you can simply use jQuery.

Comment: @codeMad, if you aren't looking to do anything in the page, why are you convinced you need to do it in an "angular way" then? Angular is just JavaScript - just do it using normal JavaScript! That's not the "wrong" way to do it.